# Tuple Array of a class

Tags: swift

how can i make a tuple array?
at the moment i have this:

```
var inventory1 = Inventory()
var inventory2 = Inventory()
// ... till 16
```

this is what i kinda want but its not working:

```
class Inventory {
 var hp = Int()
 var str = Int()
 var empty: Bool = true  // To specify wether the inventory space is avaible or not
}
var items = Inventory()
var inventory = Inventory()

var droppedItem = item // item gets decided in a func 

var x = 0 // if item drops x = 0

while x < 16   // got 16 inventory slots
if inventory[x].empty == false {
    x++ // if .empty is false x +1 and repeat till otherwhise
} else {
    inventory[x] = droppedItem
    x = 16 // if .empty = true dropped item gets in the inventory slot and x = 16 to stop repeat

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make an array of tuples ? Also, you can't use subscript syntax on Inventory class because it has no subscript members ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make `Inventory` a struct instead of a class, then you can use the array initializer to create an array of `Inventory` structs:

```
struct Inventory {
    var hp = 0
    var str = 0
    var empty = true  // To specify whether the inventory space is available or not
}

// create an array with 16 inventory slots    
var inventory = [Inventory](count: 16, repeatedValue: Inventory())
```

This should work as you expect.

The reason not to use a class in this case is that classes are reference types, and using the array initializer would give you 16 references to the same object instead of 16 different objects.  This isn't a problem with structs since they are value types, so each value in the `Inventory` array is a different copy.

Comment: Thanks that was what i was looking for!

Comment: and it seems like it doesen't need to be a struct, i can still use it with a class :)

Comment: No. If you do this with a class, then setting `inventory[0].empty = false` will cause `inventory[1].empty` to be `false` as well because they'll be the same object.